# Showing discount percentage in PHP

Tags: php

What I want to archive is that my category shows the discount percentage.

```
      <span class="box-price">
      <?php if (!$product['special']) { ?>
      <span class="box-price-amount">&nbsp; <?php echo $product['price']; ?></span>
      <?php } else { ?>
      <span class="box-price-amount">&nbsp; <?php echo $product['special']; ?></span>
      <?php } ?>
```

There must be a calculation with the price and the special price to calculate the difference and show it in percentage, this is what you hopefully can shed a light on.

Any ideas on how to accomplish that?

Comment: Have you had any basic Maths in school …?

Comment: Um... what? Where are you determining discount percentage? What 'category' are you referring to? Are you just looking to format a number or what?

Comment: (($product['price'] - $product['special']) / $product['price']) * 100?

Comment: Hi there. Don't worry about the odd closed question here - sometimes it takes a while to get used to the approach that we take here on Stack Overflow, which does require a good bash at the problem prior to asking. Incidentally, you can't assume that your audience are exclusively men, so I've tweaked the phraseology; developers of all genders are welcome here.

Comment: Got it. It is just about the approach since you can't expect anyone to be a .php professional, otherwise they would not come here for any help. Thinking about it, in my confidential zone I behave likewise...unfortunately a normal way of reacting to unknowingness if you know better.

Comment: <?php $save = ((preg_replace('/[^0-9.]/', '', $product['price']) - preg_replace('/[^0-9.]/', '', $product['special'])) / preg_replace('/[^0-9.]/', '', $product['price']) * 100); echo "-" . round($save) . "%"; ?>

Answer (score 5):

The formula is very simple.

`(Older - Newer) / Older`

**For example**

Let `Older = 100`

Let `Newer = 75`

`Percentage decrease: (100 - 75) / 100` = `0.25` = `25%`

**Another example**

Let `Older = 354`

Let `Newer = 67`

`Percentage decrease: (354 - 67) / 354 = 0.81 (2 d.p). = 81%`

**Closer to PHP**

I've not seen much of an effort from you, so I won't be making this too easy for you.

`$product['price']` is your Older, from what I can tell.

`$product['special']` is your Newer.

Now swap out `Older` and `Newer` with your variables and you should have some working PHP.

Comment: not all prices are 100... you should * 100 at the back?

Comment: Alright, time-out you lot `:)`. @uniqueHH, I should think this answer will give you some concrete clues to solving the problem. Good luck!